# Which exact CPU models are used or can be used in the iMac Pro?

Tags: imac, upgrade, performance, cpu, imac-pro

The iMac Pro's CPU is upgradable, but documentation on this seems scarce. I found out that the top end 18-core CPU is a Xeon W-2195. Which other CPUs are supported? I could try to find which Xeon-W CPUs fit the Specs given by Apple, but I'd rather be certain. Is there a list, or can someone who has an iMac Pro at least tell me the model number of their CPU?

Update: A slightly modified Xeon W-2145 known as "2140B" seems to be the 8-core base model which has recently been canceled.

Comment: Supported is an interesting term. Who / what would be supporting an upgrade here?

Comment: This is one of those things that if you're not sure, go with what you know.  Get the CPU specs of all the iMacs Apple produces and use that as the basis for your list.  Will it support others?  Probably.  But if this isn't your wheelhouse, do you really want to risk that much $$$ to experiment?  Any list you find is *not* going to be from Apple officially so the question becomes - do you trust the source?

Comment: Actually a complete list of the officially supported CPUs would already be helpful, but Apple doesn’t even provide that. With that being said, I’d generally trust it if someone with some rep here would just claim that they know a model that works.

Comment: @bmike by supported I mean supported by the hardware = it works.